# To be able to critique incoming data with existing data with POST

Tags: php, explode

POST Is it possible to match a given data with the existing data?

```
$existingRecords = "1,3,4,6";
$_POST["newRecords"] = "6,4,3,1";
```

There are `1,3,4,6` numbers in the above two codes. The numbers in the existing code are on a regular basis. *(Sort: small to large)*

But newly posted figures have an irregular structure. 
How this can be done both structure pairing?

**I tried these;**

```
$existingRecords = "1,3,4,6";
$_POST["newRecords"] = "6,4,3,1";

$existingRecordsArray = explode(',', $existingRecords);
$newRecordsArray = explode(',', $_POST["newRecords"]);

if($newRecordsArray == $existingRecordsArray) {
   echo "compatible";
} else { 
   echo "incompatible"; 
}
```

but I could not be successful. Could you suggest me a method?

Briefly // New incoming data will be sorted from small to large

Comment: Do you mean to check that every number in `$newRecords` is present in `$existingRecords`?

Comment: @ishegg, Yeah, but the little one is going to be sorted. Small to large

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_diff to check the array

```
$existingRecords = "1,3,4,6";
$_POST["newRecords"] = "6,4,3,1";

$existingRecordsArray = explode(',', $existingRecords);
$newRecordsArray = explode(',', $_POST["newRecords"]);

// use array_diff function to check if both arrays are same.
$result = array_diff($existingRecordsArray, $newRecordsArray);

if(empty($result)){
    echo "compatible";
}else{
    echo "incompatible"; 
}
```

If you just need to know if two arrays' values are exactly the same (regardless of keys and order), then instead of using array_diff, this is a simple method:

```
sort($existingRecordsArray);
sort($newRecordsArray);

if($existingRecordsArray == $newRecordsArray){
    echo "compatible";
}else{
     echo "incompatible"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through `$newRecords` and check if the current number is contained in `$existingRecords`. If it's not, then `return false`, if it is, keep going. If the return value is `true`, then all the numbers are contained. As a bonus, if you need *all* the numbers in `$existingRecords` to be contained, check if their `lengths` are equal:

```
<?php
function check($existing, $new) {
    $existingArray = explode(",", $existing);
    $newArray = explode(",", $new);
    if (count($newArray) !== count($existingArray)) return false; // if length is not equal, they're not all contained
    foreach ($newArray as $n) {
        if (!in_array($n, $existingArray)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
$existingRecords = "1,3,4,6,5";
$newRecords = "6,4,3,1,5";
var_dump(check($existingRecords, $newRecords));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/bbdqb)

Comment: Really spectacular! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to compare the two and see if they are equal.
You're halfway there by `explode`ing I would say:

```
$existingRecords = "1,3,4,6";
$_POST["newRecords"] = "6,4,3,1";

$existingRecordsArray = explode(',', $existingRecords);
$newRecordsArray = explode(',', $_POST["newRecords"]);

if(empty(array_diff($newRecordsArray, $existingRecordsArray)) {
   echo "compatible";
} else { 
   echo "incompatible"; 
}
```

Depending on whether you want to figure out the items common to both, or their difference, consider [array_intersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) for the former and [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) for the latter.